# I want to hide the output when I type in the make command in the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, command, make, output

So I'm on Linux and I've been tinkering around with `cs50`. I've figured out a way to emulate the make command that is used in the course. When I type this make command, a line will print that I would like to not see.

Terminal example:

```bash
[ja@pc cs50]$ make hello

clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    hello.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o hello

[ja@pc cs50]$
```

I would like to remove this line that prints after I use the make command.

---

Here is what my `.bashrc` looks like for the command:

```bash
#configure clang

export CC=clang

export CFLAGS="-fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow"

export LDLIBS="-lcrypt -lcs50 -lm"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "figured out a way to emulate the make command"? Are you actually using the Linux standard GNU `make`, or have you implemented something of your own? If the former, it should support a `-s` / `--silent` / `--quiet` option - see [Summary of Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary)